# split line using string as delimiter from shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed, cut

I have a file which looks like

```
60 -> 36
48 -> 11
60 -> 59
35 -> 29
27 -> 76
```

I would like to split this file into two separate files called source and destination such that the source file only contains elements before ' -> ' and the destination file, the part after.

I tried using cut as follows

```
cut -d' -> ' -f1 input > source
cut -d' -> ' -f2 input > destination
```

But cut gives me this error

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{print $1 > "source"; print $3 > "destination"}' input
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a whitespace as delimiter: `" "`. And in second case use `-f3`.

Or with GNU sed:

```
sed -ne 'h;s/ .*//w source' -e 'g;s/.* //w destination' input
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is your best bet for a regex type split.

Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt"  
60 -> 36
48 -> 11
60 -> 59
35 -> 29
27 -> 76
```

You can split the input with `awk` on a regex:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | awk -F " -> " '{print $1}'
60
48
60
35
27
$ echo "$tgt" | awk -F " -> " '{print $2}'
36
11
59
29
76
```

And redirect into two files as desired.

Comment: or in this special case `awk '{print $1}'  input` and `awk '{print $3}'  input`.

Comment: Actually not. Since the file separator is `" -> "` it is not `$2`. I used the actual output in the terminal...

Comment: @dawg you're missing the point that if you use `$3` then you don't need to specify a FS. It's one of those "give the OP what he needs instead of what he asked for" cases.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be (gnu sed)

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]*\)/\1/' <file >source  
sed 's/.* \(.*\)/\1/' <file >destination
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, `cut` is incapable of using more than a single character as delimiter.

Using `sed`, it should work like this:

```
sed -E 's/^(.*) -> .*$/\1/g' input > source
sed -E 's/^.* -> (.*)$/\1/g' input > destination
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '1!H;1h;$!d
g;s/ ->[ 0-9]*//g;w Source
g;s/[ 0-9]* ->//g;w Destination
' YourFile
```

Write source by removing all end of line, than destination removing head of line after loading the file in memory and used it for each substition